# JQuery : validate price float (7,2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

i'm using jquery validation plugin. 
i have to validate price input. 
the column in my database is float(7,2)
so my price accept

- maximum 7 numbers without comma 
  or
- 5 number before comma and 2 after comma (as max)

I already did the validation in server side with this php code

```
if (strstr($price, '.') && (strlen(substr(strrchr($price, "."), 1)) > 2 || strlen($price) > 8 )  ) {
    echo "invalid format";
}
elseif (!strstr($price, '.')) {
    if(strlen($price) > 5 )
    {
        echo "invalid format";
    }
}
```

i need to make the same validation in client side with adding new method using jquery validation plugin. 
but i can't find the true reg expression to do that.

**Update** 

detail description : 
 i need to accept any number less than or equal 7 digits like (12 - 1234 - 1234567 ) .. - .. and any number with less than or equal 5 digits before comma and less than or equal 2 digits after comma like (123.1 - 12345.12 - 12.23 )

Comment: client-side validation is all fine and dandy for immediate feedback to the user, but don't skip doing server-side validation either just because you did it on the client. clients lie.

Comment: `/^\d{7}$/` and `/^\d{5}\.\d{2}$/`, now all you have to do is join them

Comment: @MarcB : yes of course , i already did server side validation :)

Comment: @adeneo thank you for your help (y)

Comment: _"and less than or equal 2 digits before comma like"_ Do you mean "after comma"?

Comment: @guest271314 yes yes 2 digits **after** coma , sorry for this mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update
>
> detail description :  i need to accept any number less than or equal 7
>   digits like (12 - 1234 - 1234567 ) .. - .. and any number with less
>   than or equal 5 digits before comma and less than or equal 2 digits
>   before comma like (123.1 - 12345.12 - 12.23 )

Should *"and less than or equal 2 digits before comma"* be *"and less than or equal 2 digits **after** comma"*?

---

Edit, Updated

You can use `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `\d{1,5},\d{1,2}|\d{1,7}`

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" 
         pattern="\d{1,5},\d{1,2}|\d{1,7}" 
         title="a) any number less than or equal 7 digits; b) any number with less than or equal 5 digits before comma and less than or equal 2 digits after comma" 
         required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: i think the **RegExp \d{5},\d{2}|\d{7}** need some update . it show the error message in all cases ( 12 or 123,2 or 123456)
and accept just two cases ( 1234567 or 12345,12) (i mean the max values (7 numbers ) or (5 before comma and 2 after comma))

Comment: What do you mean? Only valid value is a) seven digits; or b) five digits followed by comma followed by two digits, yes?

Comment: yes that what your RegExp accept , only 7 digits or 5 then comme then 2 digits

Comment: @user6534060 _"yes that what your RegExp accept , only 7 digits or 5 then comme then 2 digits"_ This is requirement, yes?

Comment: _"no i need to accept any number less than or equal 7 digits like (12 - 1234 - 1234567 ) <br/> and any number with less than 5"_ This is not description of requirement at original Question?

Comment: no i need to accept any number less than or equal 7 digits like (12 - 1234 - 1234567 ) .. - .. 
and any number with less than or equal 5 digits before comma and less than or equal 2 digits before comma like (123.1 - 12345.12 - 12.23 ) .. - .. 
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @user6534060 _"no i need to accept any number less than or equal 7 digits like (12 - 1234 - 1234567 ) .. - .. and any number with less than or equal 5 digits before comma and less than or equal 2 digits before comma like (123.1 - 12345.12 - 12.23 )"_ Consider updating Question with this description